# How can I reliably discover the full path of the Ruby executable?

Tags: ruby, scripting

I want to write a script, to be packaged into a gem, which will modify its parameters and then `exec` a new ruby process with the modified params.  In other words, something similar to a shell script which modifies its params and then does an `exec $SHELL $*`.  In order to do this, I need a robust way of discovering the path of the ruby executable which is executing the current script.  I also need to get the full parameters passed to the current process - both the Ruby parameters and the script arguments.

Comment: Don't update your question with an answer inline, just add an answer to your own question.  That way people can upvote your answer.

Comment: note that you may also need `require 'rbconfig'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rake source code does it like this:

```
  RUBY = File.join(Config::CONFIG['bindir'], Config::CONFIG['ruby_install_name']).
    sub(/.*\s.*/m, '"\&"')
```

Comment: Config is deprecated. use RbConfig.

Comment: Since Ruby 2.2, `Config` has been removed. this now has to be:

```
 RUBY = File.join(Config::CONFIG['bindir'], Config::CONFIG['ruby_install_name']).
    sub(/.*\s.*/m, '"\&"')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check on linux: read files:

- /proc/PID/exe
- /proc/PID/cmdline

Other useful info can be found in /proc/PID dir

Answer (score 0):

For the script parameters, of course, use `ARGV`.

Answer (score 0):

`File.join(RbConfig::CONFIG['bindir'], RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_install_name'])`